# Grails Twitter Bootstrap and Google Maps Integration

Tags: css, google-maps, grails, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Grails to build a web application and want to implement a google map. Im using Twitter Bootstrap.

Therefore I put following line into my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.0.2.25"
runtime ":fields:1.1"
```

To use the Google Map in my code, I write:

```
<div class="map" id="mapCanvas">
```

The problem is, that this line doesn't show up, when using Twitter Bootstrap, but shows up, when using no Twitter Bootstrap. The solution is to make some changes in the twitter bootstrap css, but in Grails I cannot edit it, because its a plugin. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The [plugin documentation](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/README.md) tells you how to use less to customize the CSS.